# Sharepoint- GetDataTable method returning null

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml, sharepoint-list

I am retrieving some rows from Sharepoint list. The item count is returning 2 but when I try to get the items in DataTable by using GetDataTable method, it is returning null.

Here is my code:

```
public  DataTable GetInbox()
{

    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("PromotionRecommendationList");                    
            var q = new SPQuery()
            {                        //recommend by current user and status is change request means request is visible to requestor in editable mode
                Query = @"<Where> <And>
                                <Eq>
                                   <FieldRef Name='RecommendBy_EmpCode' />
                                   <Value Type='Text'>"+obj_vemployee.GetEmployeeCode(GetLoggingName(CurrentUser.LoginName))+"</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>"+Status.ChangeRquest+ "</Value></Eq></And><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='assign_to_EmpCode' /><Value Type='Text'>" + obj_vemployee.GetEmployeeCode(GetLoggingName(CurrentUser.LoginName)) + "</Value></Eq></Or></Where>"
            };

            q.ViewFields = @"
                              <FieldRef Name='Request_No' />
                              <FieldRef Name='RecommendBy_EmpCode' />
                              <FieldRef Name='RecommendTo_EmpCode' />
                              <FieldRef Name='STATUS' />
                              <FieldRef Name='RequestStatus' />
                            ";
            var r = list.GetItems(q);
        lblTEst.Text = list.Items.Count.ToString();//this is returning 2                

        DataTable dtResults = r.GetDataTable();//returning null
        return dtResults;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

list.Items.Count returns the number of all the items in the list, it doesn't count the items returned by your query, you need to count the items in the r variable (SPListItemCollection)

Answer (score 0):

This should be caused by your caml query not build correctly so no data returned  for variable `r`.  Your `or` contains one condition only, you may use caml designer to build your query if you not familiar with [SharePoint caml schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467521.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)